# How to check the combination of values exists in a table with nullable column based on another column?

Tags: sql-server

From the below table all the columns are `varchar`. `ColumnA, ColumnB and ColumnC` are non **nullable** columns. `BoolCol` is a **Char(1)** and `ColumnD` is nullable.

TableName: `EXMP`

| ColumnA | ColumnB | ColumnC | BoolCol | ColumnD | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | ABC | HEL | Y | NULL | 0 |
| Second | DEF | HWR | N | 001a | 0 |
| First | ABC | IAF | Y | NULL | 0 |
| First | ABC | HEL | Y | NULL | 0 |

I want to update the Count for each row by the identical values of `ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC, and ColumnD`.

### Rules:

1. If the `BoolCol` is 'Y', then the `ColumnD` must be NULL. So
2. `ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC, and BoolCol` can only appear once. Once `BoolCol` is selected, then that specific combination can only happen once
3. `ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC` can be repeated as long as the `ColumnD` is different including the NULL counts.

I am expecting the First and the last row Count should be 2 as all the column values are identical. What would be the `Count` column SQL should be for the each row?

### Tried So far:

`SELECT * FROM EXMP WHERE ColumnA = 'First' AND ColumnB = 'ABC' AND ColumnC = 'HEL' AND ((**<<ColumnD>>** IS NULL AND ColumnD IS NULL) OR (**<<ColumnD>>** IS NOT NULL AND ColumnD IS NOT NULL AND ColumnD = **<<ColumnD>>**))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be over thinking it. This is a simple group by issue and an update join :)

Also I admit that maybe your rules are confusing. If this isnt working for you, please edit your desired results and maybe clarify your requirements.

Try this

```
UPDATE
    x
SET x.COUNT = y.CountOF
FROM 
    EXMP x
    INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT
                ColumnA
                , ColumnB
                , ColumnC
                , BoolCol
                , ColumnD
                , COUNT(*) AS CountOF
            FROM
                EXMP
            GROUP BY
                ColumnA
                , ColumnB
                , ColumnC
                , BoolCol
                , ColumnD   
        ) y ON x.ColumnA=y.ColumnA
            AND x.ColumnB=y.ColumnB
            AND x.ColumnC=y.ColumnC
            AND x.BoolCol=y.BoolCol
            AND x.ColumnD=y.ColumnD
```